# Highlight all values in the index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

How to highlight the whole index not by conditioning?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], index=["A", "B"])
def color_b(s):
    return np.where(s == "B", "background-color: yellow;", "")
df.style.apply_index(color_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option, modifying your function:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], index=["A", "B"])

def color_b(s):
    return np.repeat("background-color: yellow;", len(s))

df.style.apply_index(color_b)
```

Or using [`set_table_styles`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html):

```
df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector': '.row_heading',
                            'props': 'background-color: yellow;'}])
```

[image: pandas highlight index]

Comment: I get this: <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler at 0x1d7318575e0>

Comment: Did you `import numpy as np`?

Comment: I did import numpy as np, I'm running the code from Spyder

Comment: I added an alternative